How to disable text shadow in Tree Style Tabs in firefox
I have disabled text shadows for the entirety of Firefox in userCrome.css, but the shadows still show up in the Tree Style Tabs.
userChrome.css:
* {
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

How it shows:

(Ignore the sidebar I can't figure out how to make it follow the theme colours)
I would like the text shadows to not be present like it in the rest of Firefox.
